# Group by ID and Date

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by

I have the following question: How can I group by a dataframe based on 2 columns. One of them is an ID (integer) and the other one is a date in the format of (datetime64[ns]). So this is an example dataset of the input I have and the output desired:

Input

```
ID Date
1  2019-11-20 01:04:18
1  2019-11-19 01:04:18
1  2019-11-18 01:04:18

2  2019-11-20 01:04:18
2  2019-11-19 01:04:18
2  2019-11-18 01:04:18

3  2019-11-20 01:04:18
3  2019-11-19 01:04:18
3  2019-11-18 01:04:18

Expected output 
 ID Date
    1  2019-11-18 01:04:18
    1  2019-11-19 01:04:18
    1  2019-11-20 01:04:18

    2  2019-11-18 01:04:18
    2  2019-11-19 01:04:18
    2  2019-11-20 01:04:18

    3  2019-11-18 01:04:18
    3  2019-11-19 01:04:18
    3  2019-11-20 01:04:18
```

Comment: So you want to sort the dates?

Comment: Use `df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])`

Comment: the code that was here before worked not "df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])"

Comment: I noticed that it only takes days into account. How about hours in minutes? In case they also differ?